# Black outline removal in a pie chart in SpotFire

Tags: pie-chart, spotfire

How can we remove black outline from pie chart in the **Spotfire**

[image]

Comment: Hi there, can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I second niko. You could build a JSViz doughnut chart using d3 (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) if you have spotfire 7.9 or above, but is that really worth it just to eliminate black lines? Probably not.

Comment: agreed, Mark. @Manoja if you absolutely must have this outline removed, you can reach out to me via email (in my profile) and I can connect you with a TIBCO rep and sort you out with a (paid) JSViz consultant. disclaimer: I work for TIBCO.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot remove the outline.